# Permission denied in Android Emulator Device File Explorer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-permissions

[image: Device File Explorer screenshot]

I want to check if a folder has been created in the External Storage.

I already added permissions inside the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but it doesn't work either.

Any clue?

Answer (score 47):

`/sdcard` is a symlink to `/storage/emulated/0`. You should therefore be able to see external files for your app in `/sdcard/Android/data/<your app>`.

Comment: The same goes there as well. ls: /sdcard/Android/data/: Permission denied.

Comment: A few months later I ran into the same issue and landed on this answer again and noticed my own comment. This time it works. So I'm guessing whether this answer would work would depend on the image your emulator is using and the version of Android it is running.

Comment: Note that Android's wonderfully complete documentation says the files are in /data/data: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you are using Google Play system image.

You need to use a standard Android (AOSP) system image (not one of the Google APIs or Google Play system images)

[see details here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer)

Comment: So how can I access if my app needs Google API to function?

Answer (score 5):

cause there is system files located  and for your access device file open self-> primary folder.

Comment: but I use 'Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();',
Logcat see me /storage/emulated/0/xxx.
Is this external stroage path?

Comment: if you open device explorer for emulator device then you able to view files in path you want to see,but in physical device you not able to see those file,So i think there is permission needed if your device is rooted then you will able to see files.

Answer (score 4):

The correct location for my emulator was `data/data/app_name/` as per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer) that phlip referred to.