# Android app not visible in windows explorer, warning ls: /storage/emulated/: Permission denied

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

After reinstalling the project my package is not visible in the sdCard folder in android studio device explorer. Prior to uninstalling this wasn't the issue and I have never made any changes as to the permissions in the manifest or the runtime permissions request. When I use windows explorer and navigate to the /android/data folder my package is not present. Yet my app runs in the device normally. I am on android studio 4.0

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.example.package.MyService"
            android:exported="true"/>
```

I can see the storage permission is granted in my device.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004099/permission-denied-in-android-emulator-device-file-explorer)

Answer (score 13):

In Android Studio, `/storage/emulated/0` is symbolically linked from `/sdcard`, as this directory is for external storage. You can access the data you're looking for at `/sdcard/Android/data/<app_package>`

You should also be able to access these files on the SD card via `My Files` on the android device, assuming the device has an SD card inserted.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004099/permission-denied-in-android-emulator-device-file-explorer).

Comment: Not directly the ```app_package``` sometimes (Non registered app I assumed).  The files generated might be under /sdcard/Android/data/

Answer (score 4):

Your app folder is under /data/data/your package name/

To view all the folders you have to use and emulator without play services. Api < 23

What it looks like in the *newer* api versions.(Api > 23)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gOPp.jpg

What is looks like in the *older* api version(Api < 23)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6gQb.jpg

Where your persistent and temporary app data is now stored.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/56TIv.jpg

Comment: My package is not visible. Can you clarify what you meant by the second sentence please?

Comment: I added some screenshots. You have to use emulators that dont have play store stuff installed. In the avd manager you see if the emulator has play store if the icon is there. If the emulator doesn't have that icon that means you can browse all the folder without persmissions. Google changed stuff around with the Scoped Storage.

Comment: I am using real device not emulator. I would like to access my device(runs on Orio). But after I uninstall and reinstall the app, I don't see it in the sdCard. Do you know why?