# Understanding and accessing Android directories through Device File Explorer & default File manager app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, android-file

(1) What is the purpose of Device File Explorer? is it like a third party app?

(2) for path 1: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data
Why am I getting permission denied in Device File Explorer of Android Studio(How do I give the permission?) even though I can access this through the emulator file manager app(sdk_gphonne_x86 is /storage/emulated/0/).

[image]

(3) I used AOSP emulator as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60380916/8866238) only to find out that there is no directory of data in Android folder why though?

[image]

(4) for path 2: /data/data
I can access this directory in Device File Explorer but I can't even see this directory in emulator file manager app.

[image]

I understood the difference between path 1 & path 2 files stored through this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/47951/118418).

(5) When I use getApplicationSupportDirectory() from the [Path Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) I get /data/user/0/com.itbf.flash_chat_flutter/files and I realized it is nothing but same as the data/data/com.itbf.flash_chat_flutter/files directory which means data/data is actually data/user/0 why is that so?